# Text is all unaligned flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this design where couple of text and image what  i am trying to show everything in order.but when the length of text increase or decease the alignment all falling apart.1st image is design i am trying
2nd image is what i tried so far.

I am trying to do design for API.if a texts is long it will affect the design,so please help me on this how to fix in the base of API Data

[image: This is What i want]

[image: This What i am getting]

Code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
body:SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 450,
                      width: 400,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text("Register Number"),
                                Text(":"),
                                Flexible(
                                    flex: 0,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'KL 10 AC 1896',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text("Model Name"),
                                Text(":"),
                                Flexible(
                                    flex: 0,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Maruti Suzuki Swift',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text("Requested Litres"),
                                Text(":"),
                                Flexible(
                                    flex: 0,
                                    child: Text(
                                      '4 L Petrol',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text("Petrol Station"),
                                Text(":"),
                                Flexible(
                                    flex: 0,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Malappuram',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text("Odometer Reading"),
                              Text(":"),
                              Text(
                                '19548 KM',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 280,
                              height: 180,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage(
                                        "assets/images/dummy.png",
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 45,
                                  width: 250,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Delete Request",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the `Table` ([Official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lbE0wsVZSw)) widget if you want to align over widgets. e.g.

```
Table(
    children: [
        TableRow(
           children: [
              TableCell(
                child: Text('My label 1'),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text(':'),
              ),
              TableCell(
                child: Text('My Value 1'),
              ),
            ]
          ),
        TableRow(
          children: [
            TableCell(
              child: Text('My label 2'),
            ),
            TableCell(
              child: Text(':'),
            ),
            TableCell(
              child: Text('My Value 3'),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ]
    ),
```

Take a look at this CodePen https://codepen.io/fcontreras-the-bashful/pen/qBZOXvZ

Answer (score 0):

The Row property `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,` doesn't work like that. it aligns the items depending on the size of the items, so in your case it's taking all the ":" to the center between the first item end, and the third item start.

If you want to align the items like the example you should do the Following

Why is there a flexible widget with flex 0 ? It seems unnecesary

```
                ... 
                Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, //We are telling to all the children to stretch, it's necessary for Row
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                       Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child:Text("Register Number")) //Maybe add a Padding widget to Text (?)
                            Expanded(
                             child:Row(children:[
                               Text(":"),
                               Expanded(child:
                                  Text(
                                  'KL 10 AC 1896',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ))
                            ]))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ...
```

Comment: This is not correctly aligned with this.i think i am stick with Table widget,thanks for the help @ValdaXD

Comment: Oh yeah i realized that you need to wrap the first and third text in an align widget. Welp i forgot the table widget existed because when i used it it caused some overflow issues with large text and limited constraints. If it works for you, use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final leftText = [
    "Register Number",
    "Model Name",
    "Requested Litres",
    "Petrol Station",
    "Odometer Reading"
  ];
  final rightText = [
    "KL 10 AC 1896",
    "Maruti Suzuki Swift",
    "4L Petrol",
    "Malappuram",
    "19548 KM"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              for (var text in leftText)
                Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              for (var text in rightText)
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      ":",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                    Text(
                      text,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(92, 52, 76, 1),
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```